# Can I create a manual playlist and add podcasts episodes to it - Zune

Tags: playlists, zune, windows-phone, zune-software

I do this in iTunes to create a list of must listen podcasts so that I don't miss them. In Zune, I was not able to create podcast episodes to playlist. Does anybody know how to do this?